# Unracking the Chest Press Machine without Pedals

Tags: bodybuilding, workout, upper-body-workout, chest, resistancetraining

previously I used to workout in a gym where there was a chest press machine with pedals like that

[image]

However my actual gym just has a plate loaded chest press without pedals:

[image]

Since my shoulders hurt when hyperextended with huge load, is there a suggestion on how unrack the handles without the pedals? For example in the bench press raising the butt from the bench helps the lifter unrack the weight. In this case that is not possible because the unrack occurs at the bottom of the chest press. Is there a similar tip which is valid for this machine?

Comment: I had a similar issue, I fixed it by fixing my leg drive. Have you tried checking that out?

Comment: What have you done precisely? Bracing glutes against the seat?

Comment: [See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02xOiC56tW0&t=222s)